# Converting Data Stored in AWS back into original format in R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to use the AWS S3 storage option via R. I've been using the `aws.s3` package to help do that.

Everything seems to work on until I try to recall and use an `rds` file I had saved on AWS.

By way of example:

```
library("aws.s3")
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "mykey",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "mysecretkey",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1",
           "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = "mytoken")

#Create Dummy Data
testdata <- rep(1:3, 10)

#Save to AWS
s3saveRDS(testdata, object = "testdata.rds", bucket = "mybucket")

#Recall from AWS
newtestdata <- get_object("testdata.rds", bucket = "mybucket")
```

`newtestdata` comes back in a raw format but I can't find how to convert it into its original format. I've tried things such as `rawToChar()` but I get errors.

For info this is what the `newtestdata` file looks like in its raw form:

```
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 8b e0 62 60 60 60 62 60 66 61 64 60 62 06 32 19 78 81 58 0e 88 19 c1 e2 0c 0c cc f4 64 03 00 62 4b 7d f5 8e 00 00 00
```

What should I do to convert this file back to its original form?

Comment: When you run `class(newtestdata)`, what is the output?  Is there perhaps another wrapper function which you need to call after retrieving a raw object from an S3 bucket?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it just says `"raw"`

Comment: There are also no `attributes` to the object. If I try `rawConnection(newtestdata)` I get:  A connection with description "newtestdata"  
class       "rawConnection"
mode        "r"            
text        "binary"       
opened      "opened"       
can read    "yes"          
can write   "no"

Comment: Please read the official [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/aws.s3.pdf) for this package.  I can't fix your problem with having R and S3 in front of me, which I unfortunately don't have right now.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, yup I've tried the solutions listed in the documentation, as well as those listed here https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3. Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Can you try s3readRDS(object = "mtcars.rds", bucket = "myexamplebucket") as mentioned in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.12/topics/s3saveRDS and see if it they are matching with identical(mtcars, mtcars2)

Comment: @bdcloud solved thanks. Clearly I needed to read more. if you provide it in answer form I can tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below snippet to read the data as it is as mentioned in [[1]](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.12/topics/s3saveRDS) and see if it they are matching with identical() .

```
s3readRDS(object = "mtcars.rds", bucket = "myexamplebucket")
identical(mtcars, mtcars2)
```